# How to Choose A Specific Graphics Device in SharpDX/DirectX 11?

Tags: c#, directx, directx-11, sharpdx

My system has two graphics cards installed: a Quadro FX 1500, which supports up to DirectX 9, and a Quadro 600, which supports up to DirectX 11. I'm writing a C# application (using the SharpDX wrapper library) against DirectX 11, so I want to make sure that I'm always choosing the Quadro 600 as my device. Will DirectX 11 select the correct device/graphics card by default, or if not, is there a way I can enumerate the devices on my system and choose the one that supports DirectX 11?

Right now my device initialization code looks like this:

```
//which device do we get?
SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device defaultDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've confirmed that the device is using feature set 9.3 (via `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.GetSupportedFeatureLevel()`), so the default device must be the FX 1500. Still not sure how to correct that, however.

Comment: Yes, but you can do this via DXGI, not DirectX, have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075(v=vs.85).aspx under "Enumerate Adapters"

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a device for a specific adapter, you need to pass it as argument in the device constructor.

First get the device index that you need :

```
SharpDX.DXGI.Factory f = new SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1();
SharpDX.DXGI.Adapter a = f.GetAdapter(adapterindex);
FeatureLevel[] levels = new FeatureLevel[]
{
#if DIRECTX11_1
    FeatureLevel.Level_11_1,
#endif
    FeatureLevel.Level_11_0,
    FeatureLevel.Level_10_1,
    FeatureLevel.Level_10_0,
    FeatureLevel.Level_9_3
};

DeviceCreationFlags flags = DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport;

var dev = new Device(a, flags, levels);
```

To find the right adapter, you can loop GetAdapter function, and use Description to find the one you need.

Please note that you should not use the Hardware flag in case you specify a device manually. BgraSupport is common practice.